# Create a list of artifacts that are build by a maven project

Tags: java, maven, build, build-process

Is there a way to create a list of all artifacts that are created by running

```
mvn clean install
```

similar to the output of :

```
mvn mvn dependency:tree/list
```

Comment: Yes, run `mvn clean install` :). There's no other way I think.

Comment: `mvn clean install | grep "^\[INFO\] Installing " | grep -v " at end" | grep -v "Installing artifact "  | cut -d" " -f5"` For which purpose? Are you building in Jenkins ? Than you can use the REST API to get those information ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Theres an extra quote at the end... It should be mvn clean install | grep "^\[INFO\] Installing " | grep -v " at end" | grep -v "Installing artifact " | cut -d" " -f5

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at: https://github.com/khmarbaise/deployment-recorder-extension

Answer (score 15):

There is a way to do that:

```
mvn -q -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${project.groupId} ${project.version} ${project.artifactId} ${project.packaging}' --non-recursive exec:exec
```

If you want it for all artifacts in your project including sub-folders remove `--non-recursive`.

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved by writing a maven extension by extending `org.apache.maven.AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant` which will run at the end of maven build `afterSessionEnd` and using `MavenSession.getAllProjects(), Artifact.getArtifact(), getAttachedArtifacts(), getGroupID(), getArtifactId(), getClassifier(), getType()` you can loop through all the projects and get the details for each artifact generated.
make sure to set the correct profile(if you have any) to not miss any info about the artifacts like reported here [get classifier/id of maven assembly artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402490/get-classifier-id-of-maven-assembly-artifact/48575766#48575766)