# how to print all the maven artifacts list which will be generated during the build?

Tags: maven

Is there a way to print all the maven build artficats which will be generated by a Maven project without running it ?
Tried something which is given here [Create a list of artifacts that are build by a maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936238/create-a-list-of-artifacts-that-are-build-by-a-maven-project) 
But it doesn't print all the artifacts. if project generates more than 1 artiafct then it lists only one artifact which is primary.

Comment: command you have used to print the list

Comment: mvn -q -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${project.groupId} ${project.version} ${project.artifactId}' exec:exec
mvn -q -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${project.groupId} ${project.version} ${project.artifactId} ${project.artifact}' exec:exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

managed to achieve this in different way. by writing an extension which gives all the artiafcts info at the end of the build. 
check it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48575858/7315297