# get classifier/id of maven assembly artifact

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

We have a Maven extension which runs `afterSessionEnd` to get all the artifacts details generated during the maven build, it prints GAV of each artifact using 
    `MavenSession.getAllProjects(), Artifact.getArtifact(), getAttachedArtifacts(), getGroupID(), getArtifactId(), getClassifier(), getType()` methods.
It works fine generally, but if there are any assemblies being generated in the maven project it doesn't print classifier/ID of that assembly artifact even though using `getClassifier()`, Is there any way to get it also ?

Comment: Facing same issues with maven rpm projects, classifiers were not returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that problem was due to active profile setup.
It is fixed by setting up the correct active profile of the session, using `org.apache.maven.model.Profile getActiveProfiles(), setProperty(), setActivation()`
and now it gives all the missing info for all the artifacts including assemblies and rpm's (with classifiers).